# How do you import files from outside the current dir?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an app with a backend repo and 2 frontend repos

I now want to share code from the 2 frontend repos

```
app/
mySecondApp/
```

but I can't seem to import stuff from one to another?

in say: `app/components/myComponent` I want to import `mySecondApp/util/utilFunction`

I've tried doing `../../../../../../../mySecondApp/util/utilFunction` this even though VScode autocompleted, react is saying it's an unused import

but it wont pick it up, do I need to change something in create-react-app, use lerna, or something in tsconfig?

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about your deployed app or local build? It seems it will be different paths since they are two independent apps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a package manager like npm or yarn to install the shared code as a package in both repositories?

This will allow you to import the shared code using a simple package name rather than a relative file path.

Alternatively, you can consider using a monorepo tool like Lerna to manage multiple packages within a single repository.